# Multi Head monitor with Intel HD Graphics - random black screen

Tags: xrandr, multi-monitor, intel-graphics

I experience some troubles with a 3-head monitors configuration :

- hardware is an Intel NUC Core i5 - HD Graphics 4000 with 3 outputs (1 HDMI, 2 Mini-DP)
- debian wheezy, kernel 3.2

My Xorg configuration works well: one desktop on three screens, with xrandr commands to resize each screen and set position ... but the result is exactly what I need and works fine.

Randomly at X start, one of the 3 screens - generally the same but sometimes another - remains black (not really black, more in stand by). And randomly 3 works well.

For xrandr and xset q, everything is ok.
I can get the black screen back with a:

```
xset dpms force off && xset dpms force on
```

(a `chvt 6 && chvt 7` works well too)

This command gives me the 3 screens back, or one of these remains black (not always the same), but at 3th or 4th attempt, it's ok.
The problem is exactly the same with different monitors and different NUC.

The point is I want it working by itself, without any interactions. So I'm searching a way:

- to detect when one monitor is in this "black" mode (to run automaticaly the xset command until all screens are ok). But I have no leads to detect that.
- or to be sure the screens are "waked up", as a regular poke

How can I solve this?

Comment: Any solution to this?